# Can I research in web technologies with an academic approach?

Tags: reference-request

I'm an undergraduate computer engineering student. I know that I like to become a researcher in my major in the future. I also work as a junior web developer at a small start-up, and I think I really like web and web technologies. Can I do research in this field and are there problems about web technologies that can be solved by academic research? If so, where should I start? What should I study in order to be prepared to work on these problems? How can I find open problems about the web?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being a web developer, I am sure you realize that most large scale websites contain at least one of databases, high availability server, front end design, an algorithm of some sort, etc.

Each of these areas has an active research community. Database researchers mostly study data structures and algorithms that speed up database operations. UI/UX researchers study human-computer interactions, to find better designs and UIs for users to consume. The algorithm community studies characterising various algorithmic problems and finding fast algorithms for them. The distributed systems researchers study how to build high functioning and available servers. This is of course in no way a summary, but it should give you an idea.

So to answer your question, web research is a very generic field that involves and combines many different disciplines. You’ll have to narrow down exactly what you’re interested in web development before participating in their respective research communities.